# Understanding custom abs function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, ternary-operator

I hope my logic isn't flawed but I'm reading the Definitive Guide to JavaScript and I don't understand how this custom abs function works...

```
function abs(x) {
  if (x >= 0) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return -x;
  }
}
```

I recrafted it using a ternary operator in an attempt to understand it...

```
var res = (x >= 0) ? x : -x;
return res;
```

... but I still don't get how it works.

Say I use -10 as x, how does it return +10? How does the sign reverse?

Comment: Although I have found the degree of mathematical knowledge needed to code in most cases to be far lower than expected, you do need some understanding of the basics – the principles of operator precedence, say, or, in this case, the rules governing the interaction of positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I really wish I had a stronger grasp of mathematics. I am actively seeking to improve this skill and apply it to programming. I know P.E.M.D.A.S and the rules that govern these numbers but I didn't understand how return -x works. Replacing x with -10, I thought it replaced the negative also... but thinking deeper into it, it just replaces the x with (-10) and leaves the - sign in front of the (-10) which evaluates to 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function abs(x) {
    if (x >= 0) {

        //If the number passed is greater than or equal to zero (positive)
        //return it back as is
        return x;

    } else {

        //If less than zero (negative)
        //return the negative of it (which makes it positive)
        // -(-10) === 10
        return -x;

    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that you would have to multiply -10 by -1 to change the sign but keep the value of it. Here's what I was thinking of, return -x * -1; but I guess that would just make it negative again. I thought -10 would just override the negative in the parameter and it would remain -10.

Answer (score 3):

Negative 10 is not greater than or equal to 0, so its opposite is returned.

Placing a negative sign in front of a variable is the same thing as multiplying it by negative 1.

Answer (score 2):

it look as

```
var res = (x >= 0) ? 1 * x : -1 * x;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Say I use -10 as x, how does it return +10? How does the sign reverse?

That's because of this check:

```
x >= 0
```

If number is 0 or greater it returns it `else` returns negative version which becomes positive because of `-` sign before it.